# Sorting in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Does anyone know how to do sorting in Unity ScrollView?

currently, I have a Scroll View with this(*picture) hierarchy

[image: what I have]

I would like it to sort, like in the picture below, when I click a button

[image: what I want]

Answer (score 1):

Change the index of the object that you want to be in a different position. First child is at the top of your list, last at the bottom.

There is also a call to set as last sibling and first sibling

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sortingOrder.html

Comment: Hi Hichem, thank you for your answer... I'm not sure that i really understand it thought.... へ[ •́ ‸ •̀ ]ʋ
I would like it to have it sort automatically with a button click.

Answer (score 0):

And then Unity Preferences-> Generel Enable SortObject this is Editor Script

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

 public class SortObject : BaseHierarchySort
  {
    public override int Compare(GameObject obj1, GameObject obj2)
     {
        if (obj1 == obj2) return 0;
        if (obj1 == null) return -1;
        if (obj2 == null) return 1;
        return EditorUtility.NaturalCompare(obj1.name, obj2.name);
      } 
  }
```